# Mysql Incorrect optimiser work

Tags: mysql, percona

I have the next innodb table:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  server int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  internal_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  pid int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  event_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  event_stamp int(11) NOT NULL,
  status tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX IDX_events (event_stamp, pid),
  INDEX IDX_events2 (event_stamp),
  UNIQUE INDEX UK_events_hash (internal_id, server)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

The records count is **~ 5 millions**. When I execute the next SQL:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, internal_id, pid, status FROM events WHERE event_stamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());
```

Profiler says that there are 2 possible indexes, but none is used. Total execute time is 0.105 ms. Then I add "`FORCE INDEX (IDX_events2)`" and profiler says that the index is used and total execute time is 0.02 ms.

So why does optimiser think that not using index and go through the ~2 mln records is faster than using index ? Executing with index more faster and it was logical.

Explain output:
`1  SIMPLE  c   (null)  ALL IDX_events,IDX_events2  (null)  (null)  (null)  5944539 50  Using where`

and with force:
`1  SIMPLE  c   (null)  range   IDX_events2 IDX_events2 4   (null)  2972269 100 Using index condition`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding: 0.105ms is longer than 0.020ms.

Comment: Yes, and that I don't understand why optimiser didn't use index. With force index it's faster

Comment: Provide us the explain with the force and without force

Comment: @Noob  Ok, i added explain output to the question.

Comment: @hadwin please provide not only the ouput but the whole query and output

Comment: @Noob yes, I provide query in question. Or you ask output of select ? It will be big :)

Comment: @hadwin give use the query you used for the explain.

Comment: @Noob EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, internal_id, pid, status FROM events WHERE event_stamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());

Comment: @hadwin it is still hard and almost hard to believe that the index is faster then the query without force. Could you give us some sample data so we can reproduce this in our own setup ?

Answer (score 2):

The most database uses B tree for indexing. In this case the database optimizer don't use the index because its faster to scan without index

2mil / 5mil > 20% and I guess it is faster to do table scan then using the index. Index is not always the best solution [Avoid full table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html)

> The output from EXPLAIN shows ALL in the type column when MySQL uses a
>   full table scan to resolve a query. This usually happens under the
>   following conditions:
>
> You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key
>   value) through another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by
>   using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table
>   scan would be faster.

In your query your using range operators. In most cases its faster to avoid the index scan. When your creating index it cost more to scan the index pages for a match.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But real execute shows that with force using index it's much faster (105 ms without index and 20ms with force - 400% faster). So in that I dont understand why optimiser think that table scan faster